# Can a ClearCase trigger be supressed by another ClearCase trigger?

Tags: triggers, clearcase

I have a ClearCase trigger that runs a script after the `checkin` operation has been performed.
It works when a user checks in a new element version or adds a new element to source control.

When a file is deleted, however, I do not want the trigger to fire (or at least I don't want the script associated to it to run), but I know it will because after an element is removed, the folder is inevitably checked in.

Is the a way for an `rmelem` operation trigger to somehow suppress the `checkin` operation trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do that by:

- defining a preop trigger on `rmelem` which sets a flag (like a file written somewhere accessible by any client)
- modifying your postop trigger on `checkin` which, is that file exists, will delete it and *not* execute the rest of the trigger.

But my point is: as far as I know, those triggers are independent one from the others, so you need to come up with an external *coordination* mechanism in order for one trigger to influence another trigger.

You could also play with environment variable (if a certain EV is set, then then postop trigger unset it and don't execute itself), but I am not sure if you can set *and* persists EV accross different execution of different trigger.

Comment: Genius! I will definitely take this into consideration! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if the trigger has to be run for all element types.

You can distinguish in your script if the element is a directory or a file element using the env var CLEARCASE_ELTYPE. Maybe that helps?

Another point is the env var PPID - the fine manual says:
You can use the CLEARCASE_PPID environment variable to help synchronize multiple firings ...##